# How do I install fusionpbx on my Amazon server(aws)?

Tags: freeswitch, fusionpbx

I installed centos7 on aws. And I installed aws with the usual Fusionpbx installation method. However, after I installed Fusionpbx, ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error occurred when I connected to https: //  in window10.
Even if you disable HTTP and HTTPS inbound on the firewall, the error still exists.
How do I install fusionpbx on aws?

Answer (score 0):

The install instructions for CentOS and other Operating Systems are located here. The preferred and most polished operating systems for FusionPBX are Debian (preferred by FreeSWITCH Developers), FreeBSD, CentOS in that order.
https://github.com/fusionpbx/fusionpbx-install.sh

Instructions here may also help for Amazon AWS
https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Amazon+EC2